# using DAX count number rows where column contains a specific string

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

In SSAS, I wanted to create a measure that counts the number of rows which the column values contains a specific string.
eg. table

|Id|item

|1|greenapple

|2|blueapple2

|3|yellowapple

|4|purplegrape

search for "apple".
i want the measure return 3.
how should i write the DAX expression?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 first **add a column** in your table

**AppleFlag := if(SEARCH("apple",Table1[Name],1,0)>0,1,0)**

Step 2 then **create Measure**

**Apple Count := SUM(Table1[AppleFlag])**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I do it CALCULATE(COUNTROW(Table), SEARCH("apple",Table[Name],1,0)>0), it works perfectly!